# push_back object reference

Tags: c++, vector, reference

As I saw this code, I was wondering that it will run without any problems.

The Object will be passed by reference so actually it isn't a copy of it. 
So if you put this reference into a vector and the object is out of scope, then it shouldn't be accessible anymore.

But it does. So the only reason why this works could be that `push_back()` creates a copy of the referenced object. Is this the answer of this behavior?

```
struct struct1 {
    int value;
};

std::vector<struct1> testVect;

void pushVect(struct1 & element) {
    testVect.push_back(element);
}

void fillVect() {
    struct1 s1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s1.value = i;
        pushVect(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you [read some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), it will tell you that `push_back` makes a copy.

Comment: The vector doesn't store references. If you look at the type of `testVect`, you will notice that it is `std::vector<struct1>`, not `std::vector<struct1&>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `push_back` methods of vector is taking care of making the copy itself: from [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)

> Adds a new element at the end of the vector, after its current last element. The content of val is copied (or moved) to the new element.

So during the call

```
 estVect.push_back(element);
```

the vector works with a copy. Therefore there is no problem.